# Why is there a difference in python packages listed in the pkgs folder of Miniconda vs conda list in base env?

Tags: python, miniconda

I'm trying to get some python3 packages installed for my user inside a shared windows t2.large instance. Since I don't have admin access I have to ask some other folks to install these packages and we've encountered an issue with the latest batch of packages to be installed. The latest packages are there in the `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs` folder but when I run `conda list` in the `base` env, the packages are not installed. Running `conda info --envs` shows that the `base` environment is referencing `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs`. Afaik, the procedure to install this latest batch of packages was identical to the previous iterations of package installations.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment and installing all the required packages there?

Comment: Unfortunately instance is in a private subnet and can't directly access the internet. In the end, the issue could not be resolved so the instance was given temporary access to the internet to run `conda install` from the repos.